# slow rendering while dragging a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable, drag

**EDIT:** Overall Problem: using top/left to animate dragging is slow for pages with complex layout.

I'm implementing drag and drop functionality on a page with heavy CSS.  When I went to test it out, the dragging around of the "cloned" dom object was quite slow and so I journeyed into figuring out why that is.  I knew it had something to do with the layout and so after a few hours of digging, I figured out that it was the browser's rendering of the cloned dragging object that was slow and not the javascript calculations.

The reasoning for it to be slow is, I believe, because the layout is so complicated that each time the top and left gets changed while dragging, it's taking a longer while for the browser to render the dragging object.  (this is just speculation.  Correct me if I'm wrong)

I've tried using CSS transform and margins but both were still rendering slow.  My question is, is there any way to make the dragging effect in a way so that the browser calculates the layout faster in a complex layout.

P.S.  I know this is a CSS issue because the drag and drop is fine when I remove one of the core .css files.

Div of the items that can be dragged.

```
<div class="pane pane-l pane-25">
    <div class="sticky sticky-nav arrow_box">
        <div id="accordion" class="s-accordion">
            <h3>Choose Layout</h3>
            <div>
                <ul class="panel-nav panel-nav-layout">
                    <li><a href="" class="s-draggable"><img src="" width="45" height="45"><span>A</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="s-draggable"><img src="" width="45" height="45"><span>B</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="s-draggable"><img src="" width="45" height="45"><span>C</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="s-draggable"><img src="" width="45" height="45"><span>D</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="s-draggable"><img src="" width="45" height="45"><span>E</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="s-draggable"><img src="" width="45" height="45"><span>F</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="s-draggable"><img src="" width="45" height="45"><span>G</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider using `canvas` instead of just a pure JS/CSS solution.

Comment: Does it contain images? Code would be useful.

Comment: @JakeGould do you mean code of the javascript dragging? or the HTML?

Comment: @LazyProgrammer please give us the HTML of something that is dragged

Comment: HTML / JS / CSS of the elements that are concerned. I hope you don't have 223kb of CSS only for the element that is dragged...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using http://threedubmedia.com/ instead of JQuery Ui for the drag/drop functionality.  This solution can probably be replicated for JQuery Ui.

**Solution:**

```
$(div).drag("start", function( ev, dobj) {
        return $( this ).clone()
            .css({
                opacity: .75,
                position: 'absolute',
                zIndex: 9999,
                top: dobj.offsetY,
                left: dobj.offsetX
            }).appendTo( $('body'));
    })
    .drag(function( ev, dobj ){
        $( dobj.proxy ).css({
            "transform": "translate(" + dobj.deltaX + "px," + dobj.deltaY + "px)",
            "transition": "0s"
        });
    })
    .drag("end",function( ev, dobj ){
        $( dobj.proxy ).remove();
     });
```

Instead of using top/left for the effect of dragging, use translate.  Using translate alone will make it look like there's a delay because the translation is done over a period of time.  Setting it to 0s will move it instantly and make the dragging seem seamless.