# Html Drag and Drop - Position floating dragged item to cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, drag-and-drop

I am using Angular 8+ and working with HTML drag and drop feature. In short when I drag a div which have made draggable, I would like the mouse cursor to always be in the top left hand corner of the floating div being dragged no matter where I have dragged within the div. Below is a screens shot of where I would like the cursor to be.

Is this possible to do in Angular/Javascript? I have stackblitz link below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-envxg7?file=src/app/app.component.html

Many thanks in advance

[image: screenshot]

```
<div draggable="true" style="width:300px;height:50px;background-color:red">
 Drag Item
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! This is possible in angular but it's slightly messy(opinion....), long story short: In plain JS/Jquery you could achieve that with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217076/6336460), basically your cloning a node and making it look like it does with a regular draggable element but your positioning it like you prefer. In Angular you basically work with components and not with dynamic HTML so by that you need to achieve this with the help of [ComponentFactories](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) for dynamically injecting nodes(components).

Comment: unless there is a more fancy hacky way to do it with plainJS then it's probably "easily" done  in Angular aswell

Comment: Thanks for the tils. To be honest I don't completely how cloning node solution works hopefully there's some information out there i can find to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

I end up using the following angular drag and drop plugin:
https://github.com/reppners/ngx-drag-drop

Here we can actually set the position of the draggable item relative to the cursor using the dndDragImageOffsetFunction property. For anyone interested below is a simple example that sets the cursor on the top left hand corner of the dragged item no matter which position the item is dragged from.

HTML

```
<div style="width:300px;height:50px;background-color:red"
[dndDraggable]="1"      
[dndDragImageOffsetFunction]="dragImageOffsetRight"
dndDragImageRef
>
 Drag Item
</div>
```

Component

```
dragImageOffsetRight:DndDragImageOffsetFunction = ( event:DragEvent, dragImage:Element ) => {
    return {
      x: 0,
      y: 0 
    };
  };
```

Note event:DragEvent will expose multiple properties like element offsetx y etc. So you can almost place the dragged item relative to the cursor almost anywhere

Comment: Is there an Angular way to accomplish this?